# Twig - Check if any number in array is greater than 0.00

Tags: html, arrays, templates, twig

Please can someone help me, I need to run some html IF a value greater than 0.00 exists in the array, based on the following rules.

Should run the html as item 3 has a value greater than 0.00

| Item | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.00 |
| 2 | 0.00 |
| 3 | 4.99 |

Should not run the html as no items have a value greater than 0.00

| Item | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.00 |
| 2 | 0.00 |
| 3 | 0.00 |

I believe I should use IN, but I cant work out how to check numbers, only strings.

{% if value in array %}run html {% endif %}

Comment: Is there a possibility you can do this in your controller or you want a pure twig solution?

Comment: It is possible that I can do this in the controller, but a twig solution would be best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few options here to do this,

1. Twig solution

To test if any value is greater than you would need to be required to loop all the elements to test this as you can't break out of a loop inside `twig`. The `in` test as you suggested will not work for this as you don't know which elements are in the array

```html
{% set sum = 0 %}
{% for value in array %}
    {% set sum = sum + value %}
{% endfor %}
{% if sum > 0 %}
    {# display table #}
{% endif %}
```

2. PHP solution

You could solve this in the controller by getting the sum of elements

```php
<?php
    $data = [ 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, ];
    echo $twig->render('template.twig', [
        'data'          => $data,
        'have_values'   => array_sum($data) > 0,
    ]);
```

```html
{% if has_values %}
    {# display table #}
{% endif %}
```

3. Extend  twig

You could also extend `twig`, which would be the best solution if your require this structure on multiple places.

The snippet below makes the PHP function `array_sum` available in your templates
Extending twig depends on which framework you use, as you didn't provide any, I provided the stand-alone version.

```
<?php
    $twig->addFilter(new \Twig\Filter('array_sum', 'array_sum'));
```

```html
{% if data|array_sum %}
    {# display data #}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: So with solution 1 (Twig solution), your basically saying if the sub total of array is greater than 0 then show table? This just might work!

Comment: Yes, because if the sum is larger than 0, any of the elements if greater than 0

Comment: You my friend are a hero, it was so simple too!!